# localhost connection refused using wsl and python 3.10 via visual studio code

Tags: localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL and working on Python 3.10 on Visual Studio Code using the Remote - WSL extension. When I try to connect to my localhost I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. What can be the cause and solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ended up figuring this out, but I had to specify hostname.local (Hostname of whatever your windows is, mine was just Desktop) for the mysql host in python.